# Set value to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a activity model which has a `viewed` column. By default the value of the `viewed` column is `null`. I'm trying to create a function that sets the value of the `viewed` column to `viewed`, instead of `null`.

I have a angular function,

```
var activities = $scope.activities
$scope.viewActivities = function (){
  angular.forEach(activities, function (activitie) {
    viewActivities.create({
      viewed: `viewed`
    })
  });
}
```

This calls the `viewActivities.create` function for each object in the activities variable.

This is the `viewActivities.create` service,

```
app.factory('viewActivities', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    create: function(activitie) {
      return $http.post('/activities.json', activitie);
    }
  };
}])
```

When I run this code I get a 404 error. When I check my rails console it shows,

> Started POST "/activities.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-05 12:06:31 +0100 
>   AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'create' could not be found for ActivitiesController):

So I need to create a `create` action in my ActivitiesController,

```
def create
end
```

What would I need here to insert the value `viewed` into the `viewed` column?

*** updated ***

```
resources :activities, only:    [:create, :destroy, :index, :show]
```

Currently I've set it up like this,

```
def create
   @activity = PublicActivity::Activity.find_or_create_by activity_params
   redirect_to :root
end

private
def activity_params
  params.require(:activity).permit(
    :viewed
  )
end
```

When I run the `viewActitivies` function I get this back in my rails console,

```
Started POST "/activities.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-05 12:31:17 +0100
Processing by ActivitiesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"viewed"=>"viewed", "activity"=>{"viewed"=>"viewed"}}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  PublicActivity::Activity Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."viewed" = ? LIMIT 1  [["viewed", "viewed"]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

But the `viewed` value stays `null`.

Comment: show your routes file here

Comment: @AsadAli I'm not sure what you mean. But I've added my activities resources. Since I have no routes in my `routes.rb`

Comment: I needed to confirm `.json` format allowed or not.

Comment: try removing .json from url only put `$http.post('/activities', activitie);`

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear to me what you're code is suppose to do but please note that the code below is not doing anything with the `activity` objects from the `activities` array.

```
angular.forEach(activities, function (activitie) {
  // Nothing is done with the activitie argument
  viewActivities.create({
    viewed: `viewed`
  })
});
```

The above does loop through the `activities` but your passing a new object (with the same property value) each time to the `create` function. I'm guessing you want to do something like this:

```
angular.forEach(activities, function (activitie) {
  activitie.viewed = 'viewed';
  viewActivities.create(activitie)
});
```

Comment: Yea there were some major mistakes with the code. With the help of someone I found out I needed to have a update action in my controller. Got it working now though.